# Calling PDO::setAttribute within namespaces

Tags: php, pdo

I want to use the built-in PDO class to connect to a mysql database.
If I understand it right, the PDO methods don't throw exceptions by default. Is this correct?
So I try to change the error mode:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

My problem is that I'm using namespaces in my classes so I have to write:

```
$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

But I don't know how to set the error mode in this context.

Comment: Just add "use PDO;" on top of the php file. secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Answer (score 2):

```
   $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password); 
   $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Same way you declare it initially, my friend!

Remember, `PDO` in itself is the class, whether you are declare a new instance (`new PDO`), or if you're referencing static constants (`PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`). Since you're within a namespace, you must preface it with `\`. This applies to every occurrence of `PDO`, it's all the same class. So we use `\PDO` throughout.

That can be tricky to remember, you can also just put `use \PDO;` at the top, and then use `PDO` normally throughout. Pick one, and stick with it everywhere.

Comment: If I try to use backslashes in setAttribute I get a fatal error: Class 'MyNamespace\ \PDO' not found in MyFile.php.

Comment: Intriguing, I tested it out myself and it worked. Curious! What happens if you try to the approach of using `use PDO` at the top?

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same issue. Maybe the PHP version is the problem? Here a 5.6.30 is running.